# Elasticsearch exact phrase match on JSON

Tags: json, elasticsearch, query-string, exact-match, match-phrase

I am working on exact phrase match from a json field using the elasticsearch. I have tried mutiple syntax like **multi_match**, **query_string** & **simple_query_string** but they does not return results exactly as per the given phrase.

**query_string** syntax that I am using;

```
    "query":{
        "query_string":{
            "fields":[
                "json.*"
            ],
            "query":"\"legal advisor\"",
            "default_operator":"OR"
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried filter instead of query but filter is not given any result on json. The syntax I used for filter is;

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "match": {
          "json": "legal advisor"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now the question is;

> Is it possible to perform exact match operation on json using elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [multi-match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) with type phrase

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "legal advisor",
      "fields": [
        "json.*"
      ],
      "type": "phrase"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's working for basic case but the point is it would not handle the AND/OR/Proximity queries that query_string was handling like;

(increase OR decrease OR increasing OR decreasing OR raise) "leverage ratio"~5

Comment: @MuhammadMuzammil sorry I didn't get you. Are you trying to say that with `query_string` fuzziness can be applied ?

Comment: proximity, AND/OR operations & exact phrase match.... all are required in one query.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided your sample docs and expected docs, I am assuming you are looking for a [phrase match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html), Adding a working sample.

Index sample docs which will also generate the index mapping

```
{
    "title" : "legal advisor"
}

{
    "title" : "legal expert advisor"
}
```

Now if you are looking for exact phrase search of `legal advisor` use below query

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
            "title": "legal advisor"
        }
    }
}
```

Which returns only first doc

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "64989158",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.5753642,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "legal advisor"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: I have tried it but it's not working for search through json.

Comment: @MuhammadMuzammil what do you mean by search through JSON, is it that you want to search on multiple fields??